# Undefined variable (opencart)

Tags: undefined, opencart

on the line where the error apparently is the code looks like this:

```
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
```

I know this is probably a vague questions but if anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: Please, post the whole error message. Anyway, probably You want to use a variable that is not set within a controller file.

Answer (score 7):

This is very Vague question. most probably you would be getting this error in header.tpl because  you are using theme made for 1.5.4.x ( or earlier) with 1.5.5.x

```
in your catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/common/header.tpl
```

Find

```
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
    <?php } ?>
```

replace with

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
```

If you would have searched before asking you would have found this http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97790

Answer (score 1):

```
go to path : catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/common/header.tpl
open the file header.tpl
search <?php if($filter_name) { ?>
replace above by <?php if(isset($filter_name)) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes , it is a version defect , its common when u use a 1.5.4 theme for 1.5.5 version , but u can solve it easily (if one or two errors) using the above stated method. only this file needs to be changed : catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/common/header.tpl , and dont crack up the core files for safety .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/justinmarsan/opencart-blank-theme/issues/7

This link really helped me,

Just replace

**This:**

```
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
```

**With This:**

```
<?php if (isset($filter_name)) { ?>
```